# Display data of an associative array in a table with d3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, html-table, associative-array

I am trying to display data of an an associative array in a table with d3.js 
But i can't get the individual values in the table.

This is part of my array:

```
    var twitterDays = 
  [ 
    { 
      0: 
      {
        0: 0,
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
        7: 0,
        8: 0,
        9: 0,
        10: 0,
        11: 0,
        12: 0,
        13: 0,
        14: 0,
        15: 0,
        16: 0,
        17: 0,
        18: 0,
        19: 0,
        20: 0,
        21: 0,
        22: 0,
        23: 0,
        "total": 0
      },
      "day": "monday"
    },
    { 
      1: 
      {
        0: 0,
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
        7: 0,
        8: 0,
        9: 0,
        10: 0,
        11: 0,
        12: 0,
        13: 0,
        14: 0,
        15: 0,
        16: 0,
        17: 0,
        18: 0,
        19: 0,
        20: 0,
        21: 0,
        22: 0,
        23: 0,
        "total": 0
      },
      "day": "tueday"
    }, etc etc
```

With d3.js I'am adding values to the different keys.

This is how I make the table:

```
var table = d3.select("#datavis").append("table").attr("class", "twitterTable");
var tbody = table.append("tbody");


var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
      .data(twitterDays)
        .enter()
        .append("tr").attr("class", function(d) { return d["day"] });

var monday = tbody.select(".monday")
        .data(d3.values(twitterDays[0][0]))
          .enter()
          .append("td")
          .text(d3.values(twitterDays[0][0]));
```

This is the part what needs to be changed i think: `.text(d3.values(twitterDays[0][0]));`

The problem is that i want the indivitual values (1 in each)in the "td" that is made, but instead i get all the values of all the values in each "td"..

This is what i get:

```
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td>
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td> 
<td>39,25,20,11,9,8,2,3,9,36,36,48,57,58,51,50,75,63,67,58,62,74,67,64,992</td>
etc etc
```

i want it like so:

```
<td>39</td>
<td>25</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>2</td>
etc etc
```

Comment: Sounds like you want nested selections. Did you have a look at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the line `.text(d3.values(twitterDays[0][0]));` should be:

```
.text(function(d){return d});
```

Because you already have the data, so it is that data you should include, not the whole vector again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem indeed is with `.text(d3.values(twitterDays[0][0]));`. It should instead be just `.text(String);`, as here: http://jsfiddle.net/rKa2E/

Note: I have fixed a small typo here: `var monday = tbody.select(".monday")`, you probably meant `var monday = rows.select(".monday")`.